# Dart - unit test of a stream event timing out

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-unittest

This is a very simplified version of the problem I have encountered when trying to unit tests streams.

The test checks that the correct event has been added to the stream - it appears to work fine - for example, change the value `add( 'test')` to `add( 'test2')` will fail the test.

But when you comment out the line `fireKeepAliveMessage(message);` so that the event does not throw, the unit test will simply run forever.

How can I add some sort of timeout to the test? Or is there a better approach to this problem?

```dart
library stream_test;

import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "dart:async";

void main() {
   test("aa", () {
   StreamController streamController = new StreamController();

   streamController.add( "test");
   Stream underTest = streamController.stream;

   underTest.first.then(expectAsync((e){
        expect( e, equals( "test"));
   })); 
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like:

```dart
library stream_test;

import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "dart:async";

void main() {
  test("aa", () {
    StreamController streamController = new StreamController();

    Timer t;

    Stream underTest = streamController.stream;
    underTest.first.then(expectAsync((e) {
      expect(e, equals("test"));
      if (t != null) {
        t.cancel();
      }
    }));

    t = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      fail('event not fired in time');
    });

    streamController.add("test");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter. As always you come riding to the rescue to help me on my quest to unit test async code :)

Answer (score 0):

Stream class has method for this.

```dart
 Stream timeout(Duration timeLimit, {Function void onTimeout(EventSinksink)})
```

> Creates a new stream with the same events as this stream.
>
> Whenever more than timeLimit passes between two events from this
>   stream, the onTimeout function is called.
>
> The countdown doesn't start until the returned stream is listened to.
>   The countdown is reset every time an event is forwarded from this
>   stream, or when the stream is paused and resumed.
>
> The onTimeout function is called with one argument: an
>   dart-async.EventSink that allows putting events into the returned
>   stream. This EventSink is only valid during the call to onTimeout.
>
> If onTimeout is omitted, a timeout will just put a
>   dart-async.TimeoutException into the error channel of the returned
>   stream.
>
> The returned stream is not a broadcast stream, even if this stream is.